# spark submit add multiple jars in classpath

Tags: submit, apache-spark, classpath

I am trying to run a spark program where i have multiple jar files, if I had only one jar I am not able run. I want to add both the jar files which are in same location. I have tried the below but it shows a dependency error

```
spark-submit \
  --class "max" maxjar.jar Book1.csv test \
  --driver-class-path /usr/lib/spark/assembly/lib/hive-common-0.13.1-cdh​5.3.0.jar
```

How can i add another jar file which is in the same directory?

I want add `/usr/lib/spark/assembly/lib/hive-serde.jar`.

Comment: Welcome @avinash, for you next post I recommand yout to have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `spark-submit [restofyouroptions] --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=myjarfile.jar"`

Comment: multiple jar files: `"spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/myjarfile1.jar:/path/myjarfile2.jar"`

Comment: @zahra didn't work for me, 'No suitable driver' found error. This problem is due to the JVM is already started before setting the 'extraClassPath' conf.. Is there any way that we can set it before the JVM starts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was trying to connect to mysql from the python code that was executed using `spark-submit`.

I was using HDP sandbox that was using Ambari. Tried lot of options such as `--jars`,  `--driver-class-path`, etc, but none worked.

#### Solution

Copy the jar in `/usr/local/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/`

As of now I'm not sure if it's a solution or a quick hack, but since I'm working on POC so it kind of works for me.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1434041 though it makes more sense to remove those as part of a larger edit.

Comment: Just for reference since it was one of the first questions I've found when searching this in Google, in **AWS EMR** with **Spark 2.x** the jars folder is in `/usr/lib/spark/jars/`. There's an [official tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-permanently-install-library/) from AWS on how to do that.

Answer (score 54):

Just use the `--jars` parameter. Spark will share those jars (comma-separated) with the executors.

Comment: i tried comma separated   spark-submit --class "max" maxjar.jar Book1.csv test /usr/lib/spark/assembly/lib/hive-common-0.13.1-cdh5.3.0.jar,hive-serde.jar . but it doesnt read neither of the jars . I get this error  the org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf

Comment: I meant, use it like this: spark-submit --master master_url --jars jar1,jar2 --class classname application_jar

Comment: actually i want add multiple jars in my classpath .i dont have access to copy thejars in my locale file so i am just accesing the jars through class path

Comment: I tried it also, but it doesn't work, spark took into account just the 1st jar, the second consider it as the job jar, thus, it throws an exception telling that the class specified with --class is not found

Answer (score 42):

Specifying full path for all additional jars works.

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "SparkTest" --master local[*] --jars /fullpath/first.jar,/fullpath/second.jar /fullpath/your-program.jar
```

Or add jars in conf/spark-defaults.conf by adding lines like:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /fullpath/firs.jar:/fullpath/second.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /fullpath/firs.jar:/fullpath/second.jar
```

Comment: How do I do it in windows? Because on windows path includes colon e.g. D:\path

Comment: a comma separated list of packages helped me.. Create a spark-defaults.conf file within the bin folder of spark folder. In the spark-defaults.conf type    "spark.jars.packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.2,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.2"      As you see, i am getting the 1st package "streaming kafka" and 2nd package "spark avro".. All you have to do is add as much packages as needed by specifying them with a comma separator.

Answer (score 24):

You can use * for import all jars into a folder when adding in conf/spark-defaults.conf .

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /fullpath/*
spark.executor.extraClassPath /fullpath/*
```

Comment: Are you sure? I got "16/10/20 19:56:43 ERROR SparkContext: Jar not found at file:/root/.ivy2/jars/*.jar"

Comment: Relative path works too! My setting is "spark.driver.extraClassPath lib/*" where lib is a directory under spark home and all 3rd party jars are there.

Comment: This solution works! I had similar issue where i needed two different jdbc drivers for multiple DB connection scenario and this approach works a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In Spark 2.3 you need to just set the --jars option. The file path should be prepended with the scheme though ie `file:///<absolute path to the jars>`
Eg : `file:////home/hadoop/spark/externaljsrs/*` or `file:////home/hadoop/spark/externaljars/abc.jar,file:////home/hadoop/spark/externaljars/def.jar`

Answer (score 5):

Pass `--jars` with the path of `jar` files separated by `,` to `spark-submit`.

For reference:

```
--driver-class-path is used to mention "extra" jars to add to the "driver" of the spark job

--driver-library-path is used to "change" the default library path for the jars needed for the spark driver

--driver-class-path will only push the jars to the driver machine. If you want to send the jars to "executors", you need to use --jars
```

And to set the jars programatically set the following config:
`spark.yarn.dist.jars` with comma-separated list of jars.

Eg:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Spark config example") \
        .config("spark.yarn.dist.jars", "<path-to-jar/test1.jar>,<path-to-jar/test2.jar>") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use --jars $(echo /Path/To/Your/Jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') to include entire folder of Jars.
So,
spark-submit -- class com.yourClass \
             --jars $(echo /Path/To/Your/Jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
             ...

Answer (score 0):

For `--driver-class-path` option you can use `:` as delimeter to pass multiple jars.
Below is the example with `spark-shell` command but I guess the same should work with `spark-submit` as well

```
    spark-shell --driver-class-path /path/to/example.jar:/path/to/another.jar
```

Spark version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

if you are using properties file you can add following line there:

```
spark.jars=jars/your_jar1.jar,...
```

assuming that

```
<your root from where you run spark-submit>
  |
  |-jars
      |-your_jar1.jar
```