# Argument list too long when run spark on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, jar

I am trying to migrate our application to spark running on yarn. I use cmdline as `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster -jars ${my_jars}...`

But yarn throws Expections with the following log: 
`Container id: container_1462875359170_0171_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Exception message: .../launch_container.sh: line 4145: /bin/bash: Argument list too long`

I think the reason may be that we have too many jars (684 jars separated by comma) specified by option `--jars ${my_jars}`, my question is what is the graceful way to specify all our jars? Or how can we avoid this yarn error?

Comment: BTW, I can run my application in local mode successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you can use `spark.driver.extraClassPath` [extraClassPath Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /fullpath/firs.jar:/fullpath/second.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /fullpath/firs.jar:/fullpath/second.jar
```

Just found the thread[spark-submit-add-multiple-jars-in-classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099115/spark-submit-add-multiple-jars-in-classpath)

Comment: Tried configured jars with these two classpath rather than "-jars", it didn't solve the problem, I think this only change how we submit the jars to yarn or how we configure it in Spark side, but the yarn cmdline is unchanged, it's something like: {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m ... --user-class-path my_first.jar --user-class-path my_second.jar ... --user-class-path my_684th.jar, so the cmdline is too long.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again and found it working, my first try had some error in configurations.

Comment: Good to hear its resolved the issue . If you fixed the issue post it so that it can be helpful to others .

Answer (score 0):

I'd try these two things

1. Build a fat jar for spark submit application or
2. Build a thin jar with maven and install unavailable jars in the maven repo. so that it will be available to load at runtime in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, our application is private and cannot put to maven repo. Fat jar is an option, but build it is an extra step for us, especially some jars may change frequently. I wonder if there is a configuration or something to avoid this error (googled but not found), I think this is a common use case.

Comment: **our application is private and cannot put to maven repo.** We can maintain own repository with nexus/archive tools for maven.  **I wonder if there is a configuration or something to avoid this error (googled but not found)** you can use maven to build fat jar.   _some jars may change frequently_ what are the changes version or jar ?

Comment: Thanks, but maintaining a repository only to solve this is a little weird. The changes is versions, e.g. we code, compile some new version of jars, and do a test run. Each time we build a fat jar is not accepted, but want to avoid it if I can. That's my last hope.

Comment: In general most of the enterprises either maintain own repository or build far jars.

Answer (score 0):

Try [sbt-assembly](http://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) which packages all your classes and dependency classes into an uber jar.

It is very easy and comfortable to use, but you have to take care of two things:

1. version conflict
2. the jar would be a little bit large