# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl

Tags: spring, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, ignite

I’m using ignite1.9 with CDH5.9. I’m unable to run sampe spark jobs with below exception. I have followed the steps mentioned in documentation.

```
Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl
```

Comment: could you please point me an sample/doc that you used? I'll check it and fix if it's required?

Comment: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v1.9.0/docs/installation-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to your project:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

this should fix the problem.

Comment: Im using ignite in linux. Do i have to add this and build the project again??

Comment: It is enough to add ignite-spring-<version>.jar to classpath of your application.

Comment: @a_gura i have tried this already but the exception is still occuring.

Comment: @RajeshReddyB org/apache/ignite/internal/util/spring/IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java is a part of  ignite-spring jar, looks like you have a problem with your environment configuration, if you run map-reduce jobs and use ignite in those jobs on remote nodes, make sure that those remote nodes have  ignite-spring jar in classpath too.

Comment: Hi @Michael  i'm able to run mapreduce jobs successfully. This issue is occuring only with spark.

Comment: @RajeshReddyB Please check the answer from user3688187  by this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099115/spark-submit-add-multiple-jars-in-classpath

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing to the answer. I have tried that before creating the question. I have now installed Ignite 2.0.0. But the issue remains.