# adding jar driver to emr-6.7.0 spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, redis, amazon-emr, spark-redis

I'm trying to connect to aws redis cluster from an emr cluster, I uploaded the jar driver to s3 and used this bootstrap action to copy the jar file to the cluster nodes:

```
    aws s3 cp s3://sparkbcuket/spark-redis-2.3.0.jar /home/hadoop/spark-redis-2.3.0.jar
```

This is my connection test spark app:

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config("spark.redis.host", "testredis-0013.vb4vgr.00341.eu1.cache.amazonaws.com")\
    .config("spark.redis.port", "6379")\
    .appName("Redis_test").getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("key.column", "key").option("keys.pattern","*").load()

    df.write.csv(path='s3://sparkbucket/',sep=',')
    
    spark.stop()
```

when runing the application using this spark-submit :

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --driver-class-path /home/hadoop/spark-redis-2.3.0.jar s3://sparkbucket/testredis.py
```

i get the following error and not sure what i did wrong:

```
ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1658168513779_0001 finished with failed status
```

Comment: This is just a warning. Does the app actually crash (log line with level ERROR)?

Comment: this is the error from log :ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1658168513779_0001 finished with failed status

Comment: Are you getting these logs from S3? There should be some more detailed error info somewhere. Maybe this helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html#emr-manage-view-web-log-files-s3

Comment: in the spark UI it show nothing under stage and also in the log files this is the only error i could find!

Comment: The problem that you are facing is that once you add the `--driver-class-path` you overwrite the original class-path of the EMR spark. What you need to do is to get the `driver-class-path` and append to the end your new jar.

Comment: is there a documentation to this manipulation ?

Comment: does this help? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099115/spark-submit-add-multiple-jars-in-classpath -- see [this AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-permanently-install-library/) also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With similar test code, I successfully run by uploading the spark-redis jar in S3 and used --jars as arg as follows:

`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --jars s3://<bucket/path>/spark-redis_2.12-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar s3://<bucket/path>/redis_test.py`

The detailed log for the run can be viewed in the Spark history server.  This can be accessed in the EMR web console following this sequence of links:

Summary -> Spark history server -> application_xxx_xxx -> Executors -> (driver)stdout

You'll get NoSuchKey error as it will take some time for the log to be available, just reload.